# How to modify WP Query to target the first most recent post to adjust content

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I'm working with a function to grab the 3 most recent posts from the category "news"

```
add_shortcode( 'show_news', 'news_query' );

function news_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'news',
    );
    $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
            $news_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<div class="news-item"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('m/y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4></div></div></div>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        echo "Nothing to show";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

But I need to target the most recent post and provide it with a class so I can style it differently and add `the_excerpt();` to it too.

Would I need to do something with the count to target it? This is how I'm envisioning this:

news_item = title + excerpt (most recent item and will have class="foo")
news_item = title
news_item = title

Answer (score 0):

You do not need wp_reset_query() here use wp_reset_postdata() instead cause it's a secondary query and you do not need to reset to the original main query.

Never use echo in shortcode, replace line :

```
echo "Nothing to show";
```

with :

```
$html_out = "Nothing to show";
```

To get what you want you may use :

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->current_post
```

It gives you the current position of the post in loop. Be careful, first post position is 0 not 1. So you may do the following :

```
if ( 0 === $wp_query->current_post ) { 
    /*some code*/ 
} else { 
    /* some code */ 
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to add this to my current function. Is this before or after the current query?

Comment: if will apply code according to post position in loop, in your case if you need custom HTML markup you can use this condition in your query to alter $html_out

Comment: I'm a bit confused by all of this. Could you edit your post with my loop so I can see an example? I'll update my OP with how I envisioned this looking.